# Apply click event to element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I have a list of links, where when the list link is clicked, it doesn't open a link until it's clicked again. Can someone please tell me how to get this working?
Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class = "submenu"> <a class="nav-link" href = "" > About </a> </li>
<li class = "submenu"> <a class="nav-link" href = "" > Gallery </a> </li>
<li class = "submenu"> <a class="nav-link" href = "" > Contact </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the function:

```
(function() {
  $('.nav-link').delegate("a", "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
})();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: When the link is clicked, it shouldn't do anything until it is clicked again and then it opens if there is content in the href.

Comment: You should not be using delegate unless you are on an ancient version of jQuery

Comment: You want to make a user have to click twice to use a link? Weird

Comment: Your code says select all of the elements with the class nav-link. When a child of the element is clicked, see if it is an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using pure JS:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('nav-link').forEach(e => {
    let wasClicked = false;
    e.onclick = () => {
        if (wasClicked) return true;
        wasClicked = false;
        // add a class to it
        e.className += ' was-clicked-once';
        return false; // reject the click
    }
});
```

Comment: Still not sure how this would reject the click based on adding a class

Comment: It doesn't reject the click based on adding a class, that's not needed. What it does is adds a listener for onclick which checks how many times it's been clicked. If it's 0, it will add a class (so you can style it), and rejects the click. If it's >=1, it allows the click to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method is deprecated since jquery version: 3.0

Use the jquery on() method. it attaches an event handlers for the selected elements and child elements.

```
(function() {
   $('.nav-link').on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
   });
})();
```